# Problema com cors C# asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors

Estou tendo bastante dificuldade para resolver um erro de CORS.

Estou seguindo os seguintes passos:

- Adicionei o pacote CORS NuGet ao meu projeto.
- Estou adicionando o codigo `config.EnableCors();` na minha classe `startUp`.
- Adicionei o atributo `[EnableCors]` à classe `Controller`.

mesmo seguindo esses passos continuo recebendo erro de **CORS**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/api/meuprojeto/SingUp/' from origin
>   'https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',
>   but only one is allowed.

Codigo StartUp:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        var formatters = config.Formatters;
        formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

        var jsonSettings = formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
        jsonSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //WEB API configuration and services 
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Meu controller:

```
namespace OdyssAppws.ControllerOdyss

    {
        [EnableCors(origins: "https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [RoutePrefix("api/meuprojeto")]
        public class IdUserController : ApiController
        {
```

Comment: cara, eu acho que não precisa colocar config.enablecors e app.usecors, deixa só o app.usecors e tenta denovo

Comment: @LucasMiranda continua apontando erro de cors

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/SingUp/' from origin 'https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Tente `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(Properties.Settings.Default.Cors, "", ""))` e remova o atributo.

Comment: @Barbetta Olá , desculpe, não ficou muito claro pra mim  

Remover que atributo ?

Comment: Remover o atributo `EnableCors` de cima do *controller*

Comment: @Barbetta sem sucesso :/

Comment: O problema pode está na forma de como estou fazendo a requisição para minnha api ?